# How to combine based on id in mysql

Tags: mysql, database

Please help to find out the result.How to a write a query to combine rows  which has same id

```
 id   size   sizeorder  color  colororder
  1    M       1         null     null
  1    null    null      red       1
  2    s       1         null     null
  2    Null    null      green      2
```

output should be

```
 id   size   sizeorder  color  colororder
  1    M       1         red       1
  2    s       1         green      2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT id,
       MAX(size) AS size,
       MAX(sizeorder) AS sizeorder,
       MAX(color) AS color,
       MAX(colororder) AS colororder
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY id
```

The rollup you are trying to do is similar to what happens in a pivot query.  The "secret sauce" in the above query is that MySQL's `MAX` function ignores `NULL` values.  This means that in your table only the non `NULL` values will be retained in each column, for each grouped `id`.

Comment: This does assume that if two records for the same ID have a value in the same field, the max is acceptable.

Comment: @xQbert And it assumes only two records per group, etc.

Comment: More would be fine, so long as max is still acceptable for the given grouped ID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to join your tables and use case when to get the value which is not null:

```
select case when t1.size is null then t2.size else t1.size end as size, 
  case when t1.sizeorder is null then t2.sizeorder else t1.sizeorder end as sizeorder,
  case when t1.color is null then t2.color else t1.color end as color 
  case when t1.colororder is null then t2.colororder else t1.colororder end as colororder 

from <table> t1 join <table> t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```